# Yii2 Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

Tags: php, yii2, anonymous-function

I've got error 
Object of class Closure could not be converted to string
on this code

```
'class' => \dosamigos\grid\EditableColumn::className(),
            'attribute' => 'remidi3',
            'url' => function($data){return ['update?id=remidi3&dataid'.$data->id];},
            'type' => 'text',
            'editableOptions' => [
                'mode' => 'inline',
            ]
```

even I've try to change

```
'url' => function($data){return ['update?id=remidi3&dataid'.$data->id];}
```

into

```
'url' => function($data){return 'update?id=remidi3&dataid'.$data->id;},
```

I need to display id in the URL of editable grid, somebody can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to source code and PHPDoc, you can't specify closure here.

PHPDoc says:

```
/**
 * @var string the url to post
 */
 public $url;
```

Usage in source code:

```
if ($this->url === null) {
    throw new InvalidConfigException("'Url' property must be specified.");
}

...

$url = (array) $this->url;
$this->options['data-url'] = Url::to($url);
```

As you can see, it's converted to array and then processed by [Url::to()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to%28%29-detail), so the valid types are string and array.

I don't think you need to specify `id` in url, it should be taken automatically depending on row you working with.

Comment: I need the id because I can get the id automatically, maybe another way instead anonymous function?

Comment: There is no other way except specifying it as `string` / `array`. See docs for `Url::to()`. Learn more how this extension works, I'm pretty sure id will be taken automatically from row you're working with, because it's stored in `data-pk` attribute of parent `tr`.